# How to use transform from PIL in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

That's my code and I get the error message:

**`...  return getattr(self.tk, attr)
 AttributeError: temp_pic"...`**

I need to program two buttons: [**`zoom in`**] and [**`zoom out`**].

If you have any better ideas for doing that, please, just say it.

I'm going to use this image to develop maps through graphs (structure)

```
    from Tkinter import * 
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw, ImageOps, ImageEnhance
    bairro = "botafogo.jpg"
    class Painel(Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            Tk.__init__(self)                   #create ui
            self.zoom = Frame(self)
            self.zoom.pack()
            self.zin  = Button(self.zoom, command = self.zoom_in,  text = "Zoom In")
            self.zin.pack()
            self.zout = Button(self.zoom, command = self.zoom_out, text = "Zoom Out")
            self.zout.pack()
            self.c    = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, width=100, height=100)
            self.c.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
            self.main_pic = Image.open(bairro)  #load image
            self.main_pic.thumbnail((800, 600))
            self.tkphoto  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.main_pic)
            self.canvasItem = self.c.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image = self.tkphoto)
            self.c.config(width = self.main_pic.size[0], height = self.main_pic.size[1])
            self.temp = self.main_pic.copy()    # 'working' image

        def update_painel(self):
            self.tkphoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.temp_pic)
            self.c.itemconfigure(self.canvasItem, image = self.tkphoto)

        def zoom_in(self):
            self.temp_pic = self.temp_pic.transform( ( self.temp_pic.size[0]/2,
                                                       self.temp_pic.size[0]/2
                                                       ),
                                                     Image.EXTEND,
                                                     ( 0, 0, self.temp_pic[0], self.temp_pic[1]
                                                       )
                                                   )
            self.update_painel()

        def zoom_out(self):
            self.temp_pic = self.main_pic
            self.update_painel()

    app = Painel()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

a deep-copy instruction shall read

**`self.temp_pic = self.main_pic.copy()    # 'working' image`**

*instead of*

`self.temp       = self.main_pic.copy()    # 'working' image`**